# Get a list from javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a new beginner in javascript and I am trying to figure out how to get a list from this object components.

I only need to select **js** keys from **mndatory**

```js
var components = {
  mandatory: {
    alert: {
      js: ['./bootstrap/js/alert.js'],
      css: ['./bootstrap/css/alert.css', './bootstrap/css/alert2.css'],
    },
    button: {
      js: ['./bootstrap/js/button.js'],
      css: ['./bootstrap/css/button.css'],
    },
    dropdown: {
      js: ['./bootstrap/js/dropdown.js'],
      css: ['./bootstrap/css/dropdown.css'],
    },
  },
  optional: {
    carousel: {
      js: ['./bootstrap/js/carousel.js'],
      css: ['./bootstrap/css/carousel.css'],
    },
    modal: {
      js: ['./bootstrap/js/modal.js'],
      css: ['./bootstrap/css/modal.css'],
    },
  },
};
```

So the result will be the selection of only the js keys:

```js
[
    './bootstrap/js/alert.js',
    './bootstrap/js/button.js',
    './bootstrap/js/dropdown.js'
]
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself so far?  How would you go about getting the `mandatory` element?  Then how would you find the values of all the objects inside it?  Then how would you take their `js` properties?  And if you're left with a nested array, how would you flatten it into your requested structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as others have answered without waiting for effort from the OP, let me throw my suggestion out there:

```js
const extractJs = components => 
  Object .values (components .mandatory) .flatMap (x => x .js)

const components = {mandatory: {alert: {js: ["./bootstrap/js/alert.js"], css: ["./bootstrap/css/alert.css", "./bootstrap/css/alert2.css"]}, button: {js: ["./bootstrap/js/button.js"], css: ["./bootstrap/css/button.css"]}, dropdown: {js: ["./bootstrap/js/dropdown.js"], css: ["./bootstrap/css/dropdown.css"]}}, optional: {carousel: {js: ["./bootstrap/js/carousel.js"], css: ["./bootstrap/css/carousel.css"]}, modal: {js: ["./bootstrap/js/modal.js"], css: ["./bootstrap/css/modal.css"]}}};

console .log (extractJs (components))
```

We first take the `mandatory` property, then use `Object .values` to extract the values of each of its properties.  We `flatMap` over the resulting objects, combining their `.js` properties.  The `flatMap` call will flatten the resulting arrays into one as it goes.

You might want to add some checking along the way.  *Is `components` actually an object?*, *Does it have an object `mandatory` property?*, etc.  I leave that to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for-in loop:

```
for (const property in components.mandatory) {
  console.log(property.js);
}
```

You can probably take it from here.

Documentation: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: ... but the OP was looking for a solution that returns an array of the results.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the below code should help you. Please try to understand how the below code is working.

```js
var components = {
    mandatory: {
            alert: {
                js: ['./bootstrap/js/alert.js'],
                css: [
                      './bootstrap/css/alert.css',
                      './bootstrap/css/alert2.css'
                    ]
            },
            button: {
                js: ['./bootstrap/js/button.js'],
                css: ['./bootstrap/css/button.css']
            },
            dropdown: {
                js: ['./bootstrap/js/dropdown.js'],
                css: ['./bootstrap/css/dropdown.css']
            }
    },
    optional: {
        carousel: {
            js: ['./bootstrap/js/carousel.js'],
            css: ['./bootstrap/css/carousel.css']
        },
        modal: {
            js: ['./bootstrap/js/modal.js'],
            css: ['./bootstrap/css/modal.css']
        }
    }
}

var array = [components.mandatory.alert.js, components.mandatory.button.js, components.mandatory.dropdown.js].flat();

console.log(array)
```

Comment: And what if the list of properties inside `mandatory` was dynamic, and this is just one example?

Comment: OP can modify the solution above to suit his/her needs. Good learning experience rather than copying an answer from Stack Overflow!

Comment: Sure, but my point was that this solution, unlike the other two presented so far, makes an unnecessary assumption about the shape of the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the attributes and then add the `js` elements to a global list as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
               var components = {
                    mandatory: {
                              alert: {
                                   js: ['./bootstrap/js/alert.js'],
                                   css: [
                                        './bootstrap/css/alert.css',
                                        './bootstrap/css/alert2.css'
                                        ]
                              },
                              button: {
                                   js: ['./bootstrap/js/button.js'],
                                   css: ['./bootstrap/css/button.css']
                              },
                              dropdown: {
                                   js: ['./bootstrap/js/dropdown.js'],
                                   css: ['./bootstrap/css/dropdown.css']
                              }
                    },
                    optional: {
                         carousel: {
                              js: ['./bootstrap/js/carousel.js'],
                              css: ['./bootstrap/css/carousel.css']
                         },
                         modal: {
                              js: ['./bootstrap/js/modal.js'],
                              css: ['./bootstrap/css/modal.css']
                         }
                    }
               };
               let mandatory = components.mandatory;
               let list = [];
               for (var key in mandatory) {
                    if (mandatory.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                         let current = mandatory[key]['js'];
                         if(current){
                              for(var i = 0; i < current.length; i++)
                                   list.push(current[i]);
                         }
                    }
               }
               console.log(list)
          })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = []
Object.keys(components.mandatory).forEach(x => {
  components.mandatory[x].js.forEach(y => result.push(y));
})
```

Comment: Why not use `Object.values` instead?